# Sphinx/reST is not generating index for the documentation

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

The index page is always empty when the document is generated using **make html** command. Do i need to do enable anything for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~creller/web/tricks/reST.html#sphinx-directives:

> Entries in the index are created automatically from all information
>   units (like functions, classes or attributes). Explicit manual entries
>   are made as:
>
> .. index:: ‹keyword 1›, ‹keyword 2›, ...
>
> .. index::    single: ‹keyword›; ‹sub-keyword›
>
> .. index::    pair: ‹keyword 1st part›; ‹keyword 2nd part› The first
>   two versions create single (sub-)entries, while the last version
>   creates two entries “‹keyword 1st part›; ‹keyword 2nd part›” and
>   “‹keyword 2nd part›; ‹keyword 1st part›”.